# Align Bootstrap navBar in one line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, inline

I made a navBar with Bootstrap which looks different on different resolutions. If the screen gets smaller it looks like this:

Picture 1:
[image: Full size]

Picture 2:
[image]

Picture 3:
[image]

Pciture 1 and 2 are fine, this is how I want it to be. But in picture 3 everything would fit in two lines but it is split into three lines. **I need to have everything in two lines.** I tried to play around with the css but I could not solve it. This is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-mXQoED/lFIuocc//nss8aJOIrz7X7XruhR6bO+sGceiSyMELoVdZkN7F0oYwcFH+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity = "sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity = "sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity = "sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/design.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navBar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <span class="visible-xs navbar-brand">Startseite</span>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navBar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navInline">
                        <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="#" style="font-size:18px; padding: 15px 8px 15px 0px;">Startseite</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html" class="navBarItem">Telefonliste ABC</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html" class="navBarItem">Telefonliste ABC</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html" class="navBarItem">Telefonliste ABC</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html" class="navBarItem">Telefonliste ABC</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html" class="navBarItem">Telefonliste ABC</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Administration<span class="caret" style="padding-left:0px;"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#1">Stuff</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#2">Stuff</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <div class="trennlinie visible-xs"></div>
                        <li class="navLi"><span class="navLiInner" id="clock">01.01.1970 - 00:00:00</span></li>
                        <li class="navLi"><span class="navLiInner">NAME (TODO)</span></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.nav > li  > .navBarItem
{
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
}

.navBarItem:focus
{
    outline: none;
}

.navLi
{
    padding:15px;
}

.navLiInner
{
    color: #9D9D9D;
    text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.25)
}

.navInline
{
    display: inline;
}

.trennlinie
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #383838;
    box-shadow: 0px -1px 0px 0px #000000;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

I appreciate any kind of help.
Kind regards :)

Comment: I see no issue here - https://jsfiddle.net/1q7jtotz/.

Comment: Yes, because I removed two li Elements to keep the code size small. That was quite stupid, I will add them right away

Comment: Apologies, I should have noticed that myself. I'll try to tinker with it a bit, but @Vincent G might be correct about the font-size.

Comment: It must be possible anyhow to do it without changing the font size...

Comment: No it isn't. I try with removing every outer margin/padding of the list and row and it stills on three lines. You have to play with font-size and links padding to do it.

Comment: That is very unsatisfying. But thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

Reduce `font-size` and `padding` and it should fits [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/pkk7vr2h/1/)

```
.nav > li  > .navBarItem
{
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: That does display as I want it to but does not solve the problem. I want to leave everything unchanged except having it all in two lines, padding and font-size the same.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pkk7vr2h/4/ I removed the outer padding and inner padding but it's less good ... You **have to** change font-size to make it fits and looks properly because of the number of elements ..